# How to see parameters passed in iframe through source

Tags: iframe

I'm trying to pull up data (for scraping purposes) from a certain website. The data I need is in an iframe and it's much faster to just load up the iframe rather than the entire site. I can access the iframe directly no problem however it does not include any filtered results which the user would normally control through the form. Clearly the form is posting something to the iframe to tell it which results to display. However, as I cannnot see the full URL I don't know exactly what it's passing.

I tried to poke around the source but haven't been able to figure it out, is there something specific I should be looking for?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a resource URL, or any relative code we can look at? We don't know what these filtered results are supposed to be, and we don't know what the source of the iframe is. Makes it really difficult to offer a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately its behind a password protected site so I cannot share the info. The source on the 'submit' button is: <input type="button" name="save" id="save" value="Submit" class="button" onclick="$('nocache').value=1;return filter('basic', -1);"> and the iframe main url ends in ?event=filter. The point of the filter is to  restrict results to certain attributes (dates, categories etc).